# Calculating implied volatility using Scipy optimize brentq error

Tags: optimization, scipy

I want to calculate implied volatility using scipy optimise brent root finding algorithm:

```
def calcimpliedvol(S,K,T,r,marketoptionPrice):
  d1=(np.log(S/K)+(r-0.5*sigma**2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
  d2=d1-(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
  BSprice_call=S*si.norm.cdf(d1,0,1)-K*np.exp(-r*T)*si.norm.cdf(d2,0,1)

  fx=BSprice_call-marketoptionPrice
  return optimize.brentq(fx,0,1,maxiter=1000)
```

However, when I run the function giving it all the inputs specified K=6,S=8,T=0.25,r=0,OptionPrice=4 I get an error saying sigma is not defined. Sigma is what I want to find with the optimisation algorithm.

Could someone please advise what am I doing wrong in defining the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code

- `brentq` needs a **function** as the first argument, that it finds the root of. You passed it a variable. This is the main issue
- Black-Scholes formula was wrong (it is `(r+0.5*sigma**2)` not `(r-0.5*sigma**2)` for `d1`)
- the code does not work for `sigma=0` as you divide by `sigma`. At the very least you should not pass 0 as one of the bounds. Better yet, handle `sigma=0` case separately inside the code
- The value of 4 for the option price is very high with S=8, K=6, T=0.25. The implied volatility in this case is 2.18 (ie 218%) which is outside the upper bound you gave your root solver

Here is the corrected code. For the first point note how we defined the function `bs_price` inside your function that is then passed to the solver. Other issues also addressed

```
from scipy import optimize
import scipy.stats as si
def calcimpliedvol(S,K,T,r,marketoptionPrice):
  
    def bs_price(sigma):
        d1=(np.log(S/K)+(r+0.5*sigma**2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
        d2=d1-(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
        BSprice_call=S*si.norm.cdf(d1,0,1)-K*np.exp(-r*T)*si.norm.cdf(d2,0,1)
        fx=BSprice_call-marketoptionPrice
        return fx

    return optimize.brentq(bs_price,0.0001,100,maxiter=1000)

calcimpliedvol(S=8,K=6,T=0.25, r=0, marketoptionPrice=4)
```

it returns `2.188862879492475`